# 1970s/early 80s Sci fi graphic novel where a giant red and white space ship lands beside the White House

Tags: story-identification, novel, heavy-metal

Can anyone help me please, going slightly mad trying to track down a graphic novel I really enjoyed reading in the early 80's.

It was about a humanoid alien who picks up a load of humans, mostly deadbeats, and takes them on a trip across the galaxy. I remember an image of him landing a huge spaceship which looked a bit like a red and white Pacman next to the White House and it being vastly bigger than the White House, who are in the middle of announcing that there can't be other intelligent life in outer space.

It was quite humorous. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be really grateful. I've trawled the internet for days using every search idea I can think of both have come up blank so far.

Comment: Brilliant, That was it, thank you so much. Now to find a copy! I hadnt realised there was a movie, I will look that up too.

Answer (score 19):

Sounds like a [part](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6a3F6fPSP0) of the [Heavy Metal](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082509/) movie from 1981.  There was a [graphic novel](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2326577.Heavy_Metal) too.

The movie segment is partially based on the short story "[So Beautiful and So Dangerous](https://readcomiconline.li/Comic/Heavy-Metal-Presents-So-Beautiful-And-So-Dangerous/Full?id=134567#1/)", by Angus McKie, which ran in Heavy Metal Magazine from October 1978 thru June 1979 and was published in [book form](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1283024.So_Beautiful_And_So_Dangerous) in 1979.

I'm guessing you saw the book.

[image]

Comment: Originally(?) serialized as "So Beautiful and So Dangerous", by Angus McKie, in _Heavy Metal_ magazine starting in March 1979.

Comment: Nice update.  I'll add it to the text of the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much that is fantastic

Comment: @duncanwills:  If this answers your question, please "accept" it by clicking on the check-mark icon near the top left of this answer.

Comment: That's... not the White House.  I believe it's the Pentagon?  Trying to find a matching photo from that angle...

Comment: In the movie it is indeed the Pentagon.  I do not know about the book.

Comment: In the book, it is the UN building. https://majorspoilers.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/SBSD4.jpg